# Multi page Word tables to PowerPoint while preserving headers

Tags: vba, ms-word

I have a macro that moves all pictures and tables to a PowerPoint while capturing the figure name and number as well as the table name and number. I am pasting the tables in as .Shapes.PasteSpecial(ppPasteMetafilePicture).

This has worked great in the past but I have come across about 150 documents that need to be converted that contain tables that span more than one page. When the macro pastes the table it cuts off at the first page.

If I split the table using the macro it does not carry over the headers.

What I want is to be able to do is split this table into multiple slides per Word document page that it is on and include the headers of the table.

Answer (score 0):

Since you're pasting as a picture the only possibility is to EDIT the Word tables. You'd need to read how many rows comprise the table header, copy those rows, deactivate the table header setting, then paste the row(s) at the top of each page. Then you can copy each page. At the end, close the document without saving so that the original still has the table headers.